# ASP.net Double postback in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, postback

On my webserver only firefox is making a double postback. On my localhost there is no problem, but after uploading to my webserver the code is executed twice in Firefox in Chrome there is only one postback.

LOG : POST /aanmelden3.aspx - 443 - xx.xx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:72.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/72.0 https://www.xxxxxxxx.nl/aanmelden3.aspx 200 0 64 49

Private Function addperson(ByVal ordernummer As Integer) As Integer

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into persoon (voornaam,ordernummer) values (@voornaam,@ordernummer);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordernummer", CInt(ordernummer))
            conn.Open()
            Dim modified As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            If conn.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
            Return modified
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Response.Write(addperson(2))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, in the SSL settings of the website the client certificate was accepted, after changing it to ignore the problem was over.